# Can I use the same AAD AppID for two applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-365-operations, applicationid

I created two application instances [Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations] for prod and test environments. I'm now getting the following error.

> Unable to get the channel information    Detail
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:
>   AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason
>   - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '0DEC01638DF6D70A2D57DFE338ABFC3D6BD45458', Please visit
>   'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' and query
>   for
>   'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
>   to see configured keys] Trace ID: afa96f28-9dbe-48cb-a569-431f637b1a00
>   Correlation ID: 8981ef7c-9bd5-427e-bd33-072fc7faca86 Timestamp:
>   2020-02-05 07:47:17Z ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401

This log is from the test environment and now it started giving this error after I started creating the production environment using this AAD_AppId: `00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`. So my question is, Is it possible to use the same AAD_AppId for two applications.

Comment: That AppId looks like the tenant id, maybe check what your actual app id is?

Comment: `00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the app id of internal Microsoft app: Microsoft Dynamics ERP. How are you using it for your applications? Please provide more details. Is there an official document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

The `Application ID` of an AD App is a `GUID` across all the Azure AD tenant, you can just use the same `Displayname` of the AD App for your prod and test environments at most. Eevn they have the same `Displayname`, they will have different `Application ID`s.

Besides, the `00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the `Application ID` of the Microsoft application `Microsoft Dynamics ERP`, it will appear in the `Enterprise applications` in the AAD tenant which used it, they will have different `Object id` 
in different tenant, but they will have the same `Application ID`.

Comment: Thank you so much. So in this cas what am I supposed to do to make these two apps work?? Generate another AAD AppId??

Comment: @mafiguhuggins What do you want to do with the App? In other words, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to use them [test and prod] with different AAD_AppId because currently they are using the same AAD_AppId and thats where the test env is giving the error.

Comment: @mafiguhuggins With just an error, it is not helpful, could you tell me what do you want to do?

Comment: @mafiguhuggins If you want to use AD App to access some APIs, you need to [Register an application in AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app), then give the API permissions to it, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis).

Comment: Ok this is what i did `Remove-AzureRmADSpCredential -ServicePrincipalName '00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'  -KeyId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'` afterit had given me an error saying `Update to an existing credential with keyId 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' is not allowed`. I then lastly ran `.\Add-CertToServicePrincipal.ps1 -CertificateThumbprint 0DEC01638DF6D70A2D57DFE338ABFC3D6BD45458`. The I got into that error.

Comment: @mafiguhuggins Why do you do operations on the Microsoft Application? If you want to use the AD App to access the APIs or azure resources, just register a new AD App in Azure AD, the Microsoft Application should not be used like this, it is managed by Microsoft, even it is existing in your tenant as a service principal, we should not do this.

Comment: Ok thank you. Just give me an upvote for my question if it was a good question

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation is just below 15. Could have upvoted that one. You helped a lot

Comment: Ok noted. Accepted